# Entity Framework 6 big query in inheritance

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, inheritance

I have an inheritance strategy Table per Type (TPT) with an abstract class "Task" with a lot of concrete classes (like 30 classes).
When I try to show a worklist of "to do tasks", so asking EF for the abstract class, or when I try to get a generic task by ID, EF makes a 10000 lines query joining every concrete class, that result very slow. 
There is a way to configure EF to avoid the big query? 
In the worklist method, I need only fields of the abstract class.

This is my code:

```
    public Task GetTaskById(int id) {
        return this.repository.Tasks.Where(t => t.ID == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public IQueryable<Task> GetWorklist() {
        return this.repository.Tasks.Where(t => a.ActivitySate.Code == ActivitySateEnum.TO_DO);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: You do understand that there is no table for the abstract class.  So the data is spread across all the tables for the non-abstract classes.  I'd suggest you rethink your design to put the common data in a class that all of these other classes have a foreign key too instead.  In fact that relationship can be modeled in the abstract class all the other classes inherit from.

Comment: it's as you said, I forgot to explain I've used a Table per Type (TPT) inheritance

Comment: Your query could feasibly return results from all of your concrete class tables, so 
 the multiple joins are to be expected. If you are trying to only pull back results from one concrete type (this isn't clear from your question) then you could include the discriminator as part of your query, or add a distinct DbSet to your context just for this type. It may help if you include all relevant code in your question, i.e. your DbContext and class structure.

Comment: you need to actually show your code... i mean a, what Tasks is and the repository stuffs.

Comment: "I've used a Table per Type (TPT) inheritance" consider switching to Table per Hierarchy (TPH).

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases don't handle the concept of inheritance very well. [Several strategies have been invented for entity framework to mock inheritance.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)

Which strategy suits you most depends on which kind of queries and updates you perform most often.

Suppose you have a class `Person`, and two specific kinds of `Persons`: `Teachers` and `Students`. There are two popular strategies to implement inheritance

### Table per Type (TPT)

Every class is represented in a separate table. In our example three tables are created: a `Persons` table, a `Teachers` table with a foreign key to the `Person` it is, and a `Students` table with a foreign key to the `Person` data of the `Student`.

If you query: "give me the `Persons` that ...", only one table needs to be inspected. However, if you ask: "give me the `Students` who ...", then a join between the `Persons` table and the `Students` table is needed.

If you add / update / remove one `Student`, then two tables need to be updated.

If in future one column needs to be added to one of the classes, only one table is involved.

Adding a new kind of `Person`, like `Sponsors` is easy, however they have to be `Persons` and inherit all `Person` columns. If later you decide that a `Sponsor` is not a `Person` anymore you are in trouble.

This method is most suitable if you ask far more often for `Persons` than for `Students` and `Teachers`. It is less suitable if you ask quite often for `Students with Person data`. Also if you add / remove / update `Students` very often, don't use this method.

Also use this method if you need to create a `Person` that is neither a `Teacher` nor a `Student` yet, but later may become one of them, or maybe both `Teacher` and `Student`

### Table per concreate class (TPC)

There is no separate table for `Persons`. All `Person` properties are in the `Teachers` table as well as in the `Students` table.

Querying "Students who ..." or "Teachers that ..." will only involve one table. However querying "Persons that ..." will involve the concatenation of data retrieved from the `Students` table with data retrieved from the `Teachers` table.

Add / Remove / Update a `Student` will always involve one table.

Adding a column to a `Student` involves changing one table. However adding a column to `Person` involves changing both `Students` and `Teachers` tables.

Adding a new kind of `Person`, say `Janitors` or `Sponsors` is easy. It won't be a problem if in future a `Sponsor` is not a `Person` anymore.

You can't create a `Person`, it always has to be either a `Teacher` or a `Student`. A `Student` never can become a `Teacher`, he will become a new `Person` (which seems a bit ironic :-). No `Student` can be a `Teacher` as well.

Use this method if you seldom ask for `Persons who ...`, but most often ask for `Students who ...`

### Conclusion

The strategy to choose for your inheritance depends on how you will use your tables.

You seem to have 30 kinds of `Persons` implemented as TPC (no separate `Persons` table). If you ask for `Persons who` ..., your database has to concatenate the results from all 30 tables.

If you think this is by far the most used kind of query, consider changing the inheritance strategy to TPT. Whether you should do this depends on whether the database is already filled with a lot of data or not. If you are using code-first, you'll probably start with a fairly empty database.

Comment: The OP starts with *I have an inheritance strategy Table per Type (**TPT**) with an **abstract** class "Task"*. Which invalidates the whole abstract lecture, and also makes the TPT explanation *If you query: "give me the Persons that ...", only one table needs to be inspected.* totally wrong. All the tables are joined, and that's the concrete OP issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you use a ba repository that does not return IQueryable, so it doesn ot allow EF to actually use the filters you DO have (you do, right?) where you limit the returned data to only some fields.

So, what is lett is materialize the entity (which is SOOOO standard for the repository antipattern). And there you go.... for that.... It NEEDS to join TPT. Those are 30 classes, which mean 30+ tables. First, the query likely has no 10k lines. Second, this is normal and smallish for really complex SQL (which you DO have here). Third, you set that up yourself - yes, this is what is needed to pull in all the data.

Solution? Get rid of the suplus repository (DbContext IS a repository, you know) and then make the filter based on the base type and make sure to project ONLY the needed fields into an anonymous class, so EF CAN do optimization.